# Configuring grub-pc for Upgrade

Tags: grub2, upgrade

I was upgrading my Ubuntu and the upgrade stopped with the following message.

```
The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer present, or whose unique identifier has changed for some reason. It is important to make sure that the installed GRUB core image stays in sync with GRUB modules and grub.cfg. Please check.
```

I have no idea how to check this. This computer was given to me by my sister.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between options (it should be `/dev/sda`). Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.